# MySQL show create table shows extra entry with KEY

Tags: mysql

I have a table with combined primary key (X,Y,Z) and when I do show create table it does

```
`X` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`Y` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`Z` int(11) NOT NULL,
`C` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`X`,`Y`,`Z`),
KEY `Y` (`Y`),
KEY `Z` (`Z`),
CONSTRAINT `T_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`X`) REFERENCES `X_T` (`X`),
CONSTRAINT `T_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Y`) REFERENCES `Y_T` (`ID`),
CONSTRAINT `T_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`Z`) REFERENCES `Z_T` (`Z`)
```

Why do we get `KEY 'Y' ('Y')` and `KEY 'Z' ('Z')` ? Does this suggests something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table is a MySQL Innodb table, then you should know that InnoDB creates an index for each foreign key constraint, which cannot be removed. Hence the two indexes Y and Z, since X is catered for in the primary key

Answer (score 1):

Thats the name of the index and the fields it indexes. You can name the indexes so they are more descriptive.

```
KEY `index name` (`fields`)
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that two other indices have been added in addition to the primary key. Looks like the keys were created in phpMyAdmin since it defaults to using the column name as the key name when an index is added to a single field.